# How to update a record in lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am simply trying to update a record but it says undefined variable in my view.

My html form view is like:

```
            <form name="add_page"  data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="add-pageform" action='{{url("update/page/$page->page_id")}}'>
```

My Controller:

```
  public function updatePage(Request $request,$id)
{
    $page = $request->all();

    $plan = PageList::find($id);

    $plan->update($page);

    return view('edit-list');

}
```

and my route.php

```
          $router->post('update/page/{id}','AjaxController@updatePage');
```

when i trying to access my view it says

```
Undefined variable: page (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\dev\app\resources\views\edit-list.blade.php)
```

its displaying error from in my form tag
any help would be appreciated:

Comment: Lumen and blade views? Sounds like Laravel. (Lumen is a microframework intended for API creation, no view etc.)

Comment: Lumen can handle views but I agree that its main purpose is for API creation.

Comment: you missed to add method in your form.

Comment: also you need to pass `$page` object from where you are loading the form.

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed the `$page` variable to the view. Update your controller action like such:

```
public function updatePage(Request $request,$id)
{
    $page = $request->all();
    $plan = PageList::find($id);
    $plan->update($page);

    return view('edit-list')->with('page', $page);
}
```

For more information on passing data to views [check this link](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: Again its saying undefined variable page

Comment: I suspect you have a different controller action for your `GET` route so you will need to pass it the same way using `with()` in that controller action.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your routes method to a patch if you want to update and then insert this into your form  @method{'PATCH'}